# Rollback notices display as garbage on the favorites notification page

Tags: bug, status-declined, notifications, rollbacks

I just saw this in my notifications:

[image: screenshot of notification displaying garbage rollback number]

but it looks fine on [the actual question revision history page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1840847/revisions):

[image: screenshot of revision history displaying "Rollback to Revision 6"]

Is this a real bug, or just a side effect of [the changes to the `recent` page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope/82688#82688)?

Comment: [This isn't the first time this has come up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52758/ive-discovered-jeffs-secret-code). Displaying GUIDs has always been the case on the Recent Edits page for the 10k tools. I've never really paid attention to look for it in the envelope, but I'm under the impression that it's more likely that it has always been like this for there as well.

Comment: Huh. How 'bout that?

Comment: This bug is _so_ going to be marked status-completed through the removal of the recent page. :P

Comment: @badp'ssockpuppet But I'm still upvoting this. For great justice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It has always been this way.
2. We're deprecating the /recent pages, so no further work of any kind will be done on them.

Comment: 1. I must not favorite many questions that get edits rolled back; 2. __even if a `/recent` page starts leaking radioactive waste onto kittens, puppies _and_ baby unicorns!?!?!?!?!?__

Comment: 2. So you're _really_ going to take it away from us? I'm hoping for a proper substitute that shows the **recent** changes since my last visit!